# Selecting additional entry not in table without inserting to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a report in Report Builder 3.0. The table filling my dataset is missing one entry which is an `all` entry which will select everything in the dropdown.

**Approach**
Stored procedure that returns everything in the table plus an additional entry.

**Limits** 
I do **NOT** want to insert an additional entry in the table as it will compromise another system we use.

Basically, how can I:

`SELECT * FROM TableA`

A-----------B

1-----------TextA

2-----------TextB

Then without inserting to the table, return an additional value from the stored procedure being:

0----------ALL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a UNION ALL

```
SELECT A,B FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,'ALL'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I appreciate it. I'll accept after the minimum wait.